# Numpy "SyntaxError: invalid decimal literal"

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

So i'm trying to do some math on this vector in numpy but defining it just yields an error.

I tried defining the vector like this:
`vert = np.array([1.7, 0.7782, -0.4158，1.0])`
and it errored like this:

```
vert = vert = np.array([1.7, 0.7782, -0.4158，1.0])
                                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid decimal literal
```

I tried removing the negative sign but it still had that error.

Comment: You need to use real commas: `np.array([1.7, 0.7782, -0.4158, 1.0])`

Comment: `，` (U+FF0C) ≠ `,` (U+002C)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've used [U+65292](https://www.codetable.net/decimal/65292) (Fullwidth Comma) at the end of the decimal instead the expected comma symbol. Python is parsing that symbol as a part of the number. Comapre the following two lines:

```
vert = vert = np.array([1.7, 0.7782, -0.4158，1.0])
vert = vert = np.array([1.7, 0.7782, -0.4158,1.0])
```